# Get first and last character (number) from String android

Tags: android, get, numbers, character, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to get the first and last character (number) from a String, but I don't know how to do this.

```
public void getadrrss (){
    SharedPreferences  sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String Key = getString(R.string.address);
    String existingAddress = sharedPreferences.getString(Key, null);
    if (existingAddress ==null) {
        existingAddress=("11");
    }
    if (existingAddress !=null){
        EditText txt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText txt2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        EditText txt11 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText11);
        txt11.setText((existingAddress), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

 //**The problem is here**

        //GET first and last character (number) FROM existingAddress 

        txt1.setText(Left(existingAddress, 1), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        txt2.setText(Right(existingAddress,1), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

    }
}
```

Comment: do you need to get first and last character (must be a number) of a string?

Comment: what did you try so far ? your question contains a lot of frustration but not even ONE try. The `Left` and `Right` method are not in the Android SDK, did you write them yourself ? Why didn't you show us these snippets ?

Comment: I use the function  left and right to explain What I want ... thank you for responding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
txt1.setText(existingAddress.subString(0,1), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
txt2.setText(existingAddress.subString(existingAddress.length()-1),  TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

Comment: Maybe you could add some information why this will solve the problem?

Comment: Simple and effective Thank you Mohammed for this response with good greetings

Answer (score 1):

```
String first=existingAddress.substring(0, 1);
String last=existingAddress.substring(existingAddress.length()-1,existingAddress.length());
```

Comment: Thank you for responding with beautiful greetings

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try this code**

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

private TextView txtView;
private char str1,str2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);

    String str = "Hello Friends";
    str1 = str.charAt(0);
    str2 = str.charAt(str.length()-1);

    txtView.setText(""+str1+""+str2);
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks very much
I really appreciate you this response

Comment: Thank you for responding with beautiful greetings